# How to apply async/await on @inputs in angular

Tags: angular

An input is being executed first and so the value of `this._settings` is still null as to leave asynchronously so that you first execute the settings and then execute the data

edit: If I apply a timeout on the data even if it is with value 1 it will work normally

```
// should be the first
@Input()
  public set settings(value) {
    if (value) {
      this._settings = Object.assign(this.defaultSettings, value);
    } else {
      this._settings = Object.assign(this.defaultSettings);
    }
  }

  @Input()
  public set data(value: Array<any>) {
    if (!value) {
      this._data = [];
    } else {
      this._data = value.map((item: any) =>
        typeof item === 'string' || typeof item === 'number'
          ? new ListItem(item)
           : new ListItem({
          id: item[this._settings.idField],
          text: item[this._settings.textField],
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you can't do `async await` on `setters`, maybe you should look into the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook. It's a hook that runs every time an `@Input()` changes. And I am sure you can do `async await` there.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], the code you have shared does not illustrate the problem. The only other issue I see here is that you have 2 inputs that are dependent on each other. That would be best moved into an event like `ngOnInit` and let the inputs just be simple atomic setters/getters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you have 2 `@Input` properties which are dependent on each other.

In this case, a good practice could be to implement `OnChanges` interface on your component, and move your logic inside `ngOnChanges` method implementation.
You will be able to treat the different situation depending on current value of properties.
My advice is also to keep separated a third computed value, which will be the result of your logic code.

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input settings: SettingsType;
  @Input data: DataType;

  computedData: DataType = [];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

    // logic
    if (!this.data || !this.settings) {
      this.computedData = [];
    } else {
      // here `data` and `settings` are defined
      //...
    }
  }
}
```